# Convert flat collection to one-?many C#/Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections, visual-studio-2019

I have a data set that is in a collection of this class:

```
public class AOClientData
{
    public int boclient_id { get; set; }
    public string beneficialownertype_name { get; set; }
    public int account_id { get; set; }
    public string fi_name { get; set; }
    public string acct_number { get; set; }
}
```

and looks like this:

```
boclient_id    beneficialownertype_name   account_id     fi_name      acct_number
1001           Joe                        501            ABC          12345
1001           Joe                        502            BCA          54321
1002           Fred                       990            DDd          22334
```

The goal is to get it into a collection of this class:

```
   public class ClientInfo 
    {
        public int boclient_id { get; set; }
        public string beneficialownertype_name { get; set; }
        public List<AccountInfo> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

which is in a one-to-many relationship with this class:

```
public class AccountInfo 
{
    public int account_id { get; set; }
    public string fi_name { get; set; }
    public string acct_number { get; set; }
}
```

The result should be a collection of ClientInfo objects looking like this:

```
1001     Joe    {501,           ABC,  12345         },
                {502,           BCA,  54321         }
1002     Fred   {990,         DDd,  22334      }
```

Here is my attempt which does load all the client data but the properties of the AccountInfo object in the ClientInfo.Accounts property are all null:

```
        List<ClientInfo> clientInfo = aoClientData
            .GroupBy(c => new { c.boclient_id, c.beneficialownertype_name })
            .Select(xGrp => new ClientInfo
            {
                boclient_id = xGrp.Key.boclient_id,
                beneficialownertype_name = xGrp.Key.beneficialownertype_name,
                Accounts = xGrp
                    .Select(c => new AccountInfo
                    {
                        account_id = c.account_id,
                        fi_name = c.fi_name,
                        acct_number = c.acct_number
                    })
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
```

What is wrong with the LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
var items = aoClientData.GroupBy(c => new { c.boclient_id, c.beneficialownertype_name })
    .Select(grp => new ClientInfo()
    {
        boclient_id = grp.Key.boclient_id,
        beneficialownertype_name = grp.Key.beneficialownertype_name,                            
    Accounts = grp.Select(r => new AccountInfo() 
    { 
        account_id = r.account_id,
        acct_number = r.acct_number
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have reused the `c` variable to be both your `aoCLientData` items as well as your grouped items. In your inner select use `.Select(a => new AccountInfo...` and then use `a` instead of `c` to select the `a.account_id`, `a.fi_name` and `a.acct_number`.

```
var result = data
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.boclient_id, x.beneficialownertype_name })
    .Select(x => 
        new ClientInfo
        {
            boclient_id = x.Key.boclient_id,
            beneficialownertype_name = x.Key.beneficialownertype_name,
            Accounts = x.Select(a =>
                new AccountInfo 
                {
                    account_id = a.account_id,
                    fi_name = a.fi_name,
                    acct_number = a.acct_number
                }).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: many thanks for this but I get the same result as originally described - Carl

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem. The parameter `c` in the `GroupBy` does not interfere with the parameter `c` in the `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your code, I can't see why you would get several `ClientInfos`, each with a `null` value for property `Accounts`. I wouldn't even expect an empty Accounts list.

Have you tried to use the [overload of GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__) that has a parameter resultSelector?

```
List<ClientInfo> clientInfo = aoClientData
    .GroupBy(

    // parameter keySelector:
    clientInfo => new
    {
        BoClientId = clientInfo.boclient_id,
        BeneficialOwnerTypeName = clientInfo.beneficialownertype_name,
    })

    // parameter resultSelector: for every key item with all its zero or more AOClientData
    // make one new ClientInfo
    (key, aoClientsWithThisKey) => new ClientInfo
    {
        boclient_id = key.BoClientId,
        beneficialownertype_name = key.BeneficialOwnerTypeName,
        Accounts = aoClientsWithThisKey.Select(aoClient => new AccountInfo
        {
            account_id = aoClient.account_id,
            fi_name = aoClient.fi_name,
            acct_number = aoClient.acct_number
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this didn't work either